# gcm cloud connection server to app server message delivery

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

The upstream messaging of google gcm cloud connection server delivers the message to application server. Will the delivery be instant or will it take time ?

Answer (score 0):

If the link between the client device and gcm/ccs server is up, the upstream will be delivered instantly.

If not (device off, network down or tcp connexion dropped due to inactivity), gcm client (on the device) will store up to 20 messages and send them once link is up again, discarding following messages.

However, I reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22418823/) a related issue.