# Locally stored upstreams when network is down, are not sent on network up on JB & ICS (they are on reboot)

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

Here is my scenario.

When network is down, GCM client locally stores device-to-cloud messages (upstream), in a local queue (it's length seems to be 20, although never stated).

When this queue is full, messages are locally discarded and the intent contains the message type `MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR` + extras about which messageId was deleted, and `error=TooManyMessages`.

Using the TTL'd version of gcm.send, allows to force upstreams to be always discarded (when network is down) instead of queued  (message type `MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR` + extras about which messageId was deleted, and `error=SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE`), which is not what i want.

So far, so good.
Problem is, on JB (4.1.2 & 4.2.2) & ICS (4.0.4), queued messages while network is down, are not sent when network is up again. A reboot forces them to be sent. And worse, once the queue is full, messages can't be sent anymore, even when network is up. Here again a reboot is necessary.
Looks like a "flush" is missing somewhere.

This works perfectly on KK 4.4.2

On every test devices, google play service APK is up to date.

Can anyone confirm this behavior in JB & ICS, and maybe other version?
Is there a workaround?
Thanks.

Comment: Reported this issue on [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-gcm/83wpMyoz-V0). Waiting for investigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latest upgrade from Google solved the issue.

I don't precisely know which component upgrade did it, but the issue is gone on all previously tested versions.